# For Sikulix, App.close() on Mac closes the app, but returns false. Is this correct?

Tags: java, testing, sikuli, sikuli-x

I am building a [SikuliX](http://www.sikulix.com/#home1) automation script in Java and confused about the behavior of the `.close()` method.
Inside of Sikuli's `App` class, the close method is as follows:

```
  /**
   * tries to close the app defined by this App instance, waits max given seconds for the app to no longer be running
   *
   * @return this or null on failure
   */
  public boolean close(int waitTime) {
    if (!isRunning()) {
      log("App.close: not running: %s", this);
      return false;
    }
    if (_osUtil.close(this)) {
      int timeTowait = maxWait;
      if (waitTime > 0) {
        timeTowait = waitTime;
      }
      while (isRunning(0) && timeTowait > 0) {
        timeTowait--;
      }
    }
    if (!isValid()) {
      log("App.close: %s", this);
    } else {
      log("App.close: did not work: %s", this);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

The part in question for me is the return. My understanding is that, since it returns a boolean, it would be true if the close was a success, and false if the close failed. However, this code does the opposite.
Based on my flawed(?) understanding of this logic, I initially wrote my code like so,

```
if (myApp.close()) {
    System.out.println("closed.");
    isAppClosed = true;
} else {
    System.out.println("NOT closed!");
    isAppClosed = false;
}
```

This is having the opposite result of what I want, as the application is successfully closing, BUT the test is failing because "NOT closed" is being printed.

Have I found a bug, or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug. The maintainer of the project has patched the issue in the lastest build of 1.1.4.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/1811938